# Looping SQL results C# into dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, html.dropdownlistfor

Can anyone help me with a C# loop to populate an ASP:DropDownList.  I am using the following code to bind the data to my dropdown. However, the first result doesn't populate in the drop down list. There should be 3 however, there is only 2 in the dropdown list.

Any help is great.

```
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
        dropdown.DataSource = dr;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            dropdown.DataValueField = "ID";
            dropdown.DataTextField = "Description";
            dropdown.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're binding the data reader to the drop down, you don't need to loop at it explicitly (the call to `dr.Read()` is effectively eating the first element).

Try this:

```
SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
dropdown.DataSource = dr;
dropdown.DataValueField = "ID";
dropdown.DataTextField = "Description";
dropdown.DataBind();
```

**UPDATE**

To add a default item, do this after the code above:

```
dropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select",""));
```

Comment: is there a way to have a "Please Select" option on the drop down. It is being overwritten by the databind.

Comment: @claw: added that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
dropdown.DataValueField = "ID";
dropdown.DataTextField = "Description";
```

use

```
dropdown.DataValueField = dr["ID"].ToString();
dropdown.DataTextField = dr["Description"].ToString();
```